# React & Django - WARNING:django.request:Forbidden: /api/user - SessionAuthentication - CSRF token not updated

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, cors, httponly

UPDATE: I'm simplifying this as it got too long

I am trying to get SessionAuthentication to work with React (port 3000) and Django (port 8000). However, I am having trouble with csrftoken not being set in React that causes the FORBIDDEN request to api/user.

My example code for this are all here:
https://github.com/axilaris/docker-django-react-celery-redis

You can try it, very simply run these. And go through these simple steps: register, login, refresh the page:

Django (runs on port 8000)

```
python3 -m venv backendvirtualenv && source backendvirtualenv/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py runserver
```

React (runs on port 3000)

```
npm install
npm run build
npm start
```

Django side (settings.py):

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://localhost',
    'http://127.0.0.1',
    'http://0.0.0.0',
    'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True 

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
    'corsheaders',


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',


REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
}

SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True  # Default value is True, which is recommended
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'Lax' # Consider 'None' if strictly necessary and secure is set
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False    # Non-Production Port 80

CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False    # Should generally be False to allow JavaScript to read the value
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False       # Non-Production Port 80
```

Django (views.py)

```
class UserLogin(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication,)
    ##
    def post(self, request):
...
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            user = serializer.check_user(data) <-- authenticate is in here
            login(request, user)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)


class UserView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication,)
    ##
    def get(self, request):
..
        serializer = UserSerializer(request.user)
        return Response({'user': serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

React (App.js):

```
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

const client = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://127.0.0.1:8000"
});

....


  function submitLogin(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    client.post(
      "/api/login",
      {
        email: email,
        password: password
      }
    ).then(function(res) {

      setTimeout(() => {
          const csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken');
          const sessionid = Cookies.get('sessionid');
          console.log("XXX /api/login csrftoken:" + csrftoken);    
          console.log("XXX /api/login sessionid:" + sessionid);  
          
          console.log('cookies', document.cookie)
          
        }, 100);      

        setCurrentUser(true);
    });
```

Network logs (to proof csrftoken exist in api/login and forbidden in api/user):
https://gist.github.com/axilaris/f10f6eface04bd4f94a427bb347c10c3

Logs screenshots: https://imgur.com/a/juO7Z6h

Troubleshooting Analysis:
notice in the logs, that csrftoken is not printed out

```
App.js:103 XXX /api/login csrftoken:undefined
App.js:104 XXX /api/login sessionid:undefined
App.js:106 cookies  <--- this is totally empty from console.log('cookies', document.cookie)
```

Network logs from api/login, csrftoken does exist! but why it doesnt get into React axios.

```
Set-Cookie:
csrftoken=yO8XukEnOSWYgwYxae4nd7c2OEHF2UQG; expires=Mon, 10 Mar 2025 22:26:02 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/; SameSite=Lax
Set-Cookie:
sessionid=rbj2ewpg11sx0t7q9j16ika01nk46074; expires=Mon, 25 Mar 2024 22:26:02 GMT; HttpOnly; Max-Age=1209600; Path=/; SameSite=Lax
Vary:
```

- I'ved even updated axios version to the latest 1.6.7
- I tried both Chrome and MS Edge browser
- proxy answer recommendation didnt work
- fetch() has some positive progress, there seems to be csrf token being saved to the browser cookie. I tried other alternative than axios such as superagent, its the same not working result. why fetch() seems to work ? I prefer using axios. Here is the fetch() code that you need to replace in frontend/src/App.js [submitLogin(e)](https://gist.github.com/axilaris/8c417cbf212c35ece93bf0ca81bf1e4d). I'ved put this in a separate [github branch](https://github.com/axilaris/docker-django-react-celery-redis/tree/fetchworks) for review

Comment: `from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt` can you add this decorator to `api/user` to see if the issue is csrf token or cors settings. since your app work in docker env ,most likely it is  browser specific issue

Comment: I tried with this code with @csrf_exempt. https://gist.github.com/axilaris/a6b5413c7429abccb7036b8ca29cf60b. Here are some screenshot of the logs https://imgur.com/a/H0jz2Fa. What is funny is the there is still csrftoken in the api/login response. Not sure if I'm doing it right.

Comment: @Yilmaz, I'ved deleted the whole question and updated it to simplify and to be clear the whole information and troubleshooting issues. If you could have a look would be great. Thanks.

Comment: can you apply `@csrf_exempt` as this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51710145/what-is-csrf-exempt-in-django to see if it is because of csrf

Comment: i tried to install django packages and having issue installing `psycopg2`

Comment: I'ved updated the README with a bit more on creating the environment (standard stuff). I tested, it should work. And I removed postgres stuff. hopefully you can easily test it. @Yilmaz https://github.com/axilaris/docker-django-react-celery-redis

Comment: does this code having the same issue. if yes i will take a look tomorrow night

Comment: its the exact same code I have that I'm using to figure out this problem.

Comment: any luck in helping me on this ? I'm a bit lost as I tried all kind of ways.

Comment: my friend, i did spent entire tongiht but could not figure out. one thing I noticed is when I logout csrf token is set.

Comment: thank you for your time. I tried to print from django side on login and logout, it appears there seems to be CSRF token generated by somehow doesnt match. Thats strange. https://gist.github.com/axilaris/7a1d6e9ba6eb6c2d0fb14430af507c2a. Another thing I noticed, when i went to chrome, to delete "localhost" cookies, it deletes but when i revisit the site cookies again for localhost, it still exist. meaning its not deleted. i noticed this because i did had some residue cookies from another project still there. strange, i cant delete the cookie from chrome browser. https://imgur.com/a/6CCqsDf

Comment: I manage some breakthrough in getting csrf token in login by replacing this code. https://gist.github.com/axilaris/8c417cbf212c35ece93bf0ca81bf1e4d. basically, instead of using axios, i used primitive fetch() function. but this only works if i clear the cookie in chrome->inspect->Application->cookie. If there is cookie, it wouldnt work, must be cleared. otherwise it will complaint - {detail: 'CSRF Failed: Origin checking failed - http://localhost:3000 does not match any trusted origins.'}. Here is where i clear it https://i.imgur.com/h6HYHBt.png. Needs more investigation, axios using wrongly?

Comment: I think, i could get the same result with axios. I will take a look tonjght as well. I am really curious what is causing this

Comment: I'd setup a proxy (also using vite.js) so you can avoid cross origin problems. This is likely caused by the security features of the browser.

Comment: In nikhilswami answer, I tried the proxy way, it didnt work. I put in the recommendation implementation in github for review.  I also did try instead of using axios, another type called "superagent", the behavior is same as axios. not sure why the primitive fetch works. (i still yet to check further yet but i dont like fetch way)

Comment: i implemented proxy, too and did not work. i thought maybe issue is related to cra so i tested the code with next.js but same issue. when you use fetch, do you console  `console.log("XXX axios interceptors:" + csrfToken);`

Comment: with the fetch(), I didnt do anything special. no interceptors or anything else. I just replaced this function submitLogin() that use axios to use fetch(). And there is then csrftoken saved to the browser cookie. https://gist.github.com/axilaris/8c417cbf212c35ece93bf0ca81bf1e4d

Comment: I created a separate branch that demonstrate fetch() works with login. https://github.com/axilaris/docker-django-react-celery-redis/tree/fetchworks. check submitLogin(e) implementation - https://github.com/axilaris/docker-django-react-celery-redis/blob/fetchworks/frontend/src/App.js

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 2):

You have:

```bash
Client (React) --> [HTTP Request with CSRF Token] --> Django Backend
                                                  /\
                                                  |
                                                  +--- [Session Authentication & CSRF Validation]
```

For [`SessionAuthentication`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#sessionauthentication) to work, make sure Django's session cookie (`sessionid`) and CSRF token cookie (`csrftoken`) are correctly set and sent to the client. The `HttpOnly` flag should generally be set on the `sessionid` cookie to enhance security, as mentioned in [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/zwsaf2/how_to_use_httponly_cookied_for_drf/).

Since the session cookie (`sessionid`) should be `HttpOnly`, the React application will not directly interact with it. Instead, make sure the `axios` configuration correctly includes credentials with every request. That part seems to be configured correctly in your setup (`axios.defaults.withCredentials` set to `true`).

`settings.py` should include:

```py
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True  # Default value is True, which is recommended
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'Lax' # Consider 'None' if strictly necessary and secure is set
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True    # Set to True if you are using HTTPS
```

For CSRF cookie configuration:

```py
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False    # Should generally be False to allow JavaScript to read the value
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True       # Set to True if you are using HTTPS
```

Setting `CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY` to `False` would make your application slightly more vulnerable to XSS attacks, as it allows JavaScript to access the CSRF cookie. A better approach would be to keep the CSRF token `HttpOnly`, and obtain it from a separate API endpoint designed to return the CSRF token explicitly, or include the CSRF token within the body of your page and have your JavaScript read it from there.

Although... as documented since 2016 in [`django/django` PR 7700](https://github.com/django/django/pull/7700) and [commit c27104a](https://github.com/django/django/commit/c27104a9c74bc9d9e552d41f53468b103749e110)

> Designating the CSRF cookie as `HttpOnly` doesn't offer any practical protection because CSRF is only to protect against cross-domain attacks. If an attacker can read the cookie via JavaScript, they're already on the same domain as far as the browser knows, so they can do anything they like anyway. (XSS is a much bigger hole than CSRF.)

The primary risk to consider when making CSRF tokens accessible to JavaScript is [XSS -- Cross site scripting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/security/) . If your application is vulnerable to XSS, an attacker could exploit this to bypass CSRF protection entirely. Therefore, any decision to expose CSRF tokens to JavaScript should be accompanied by rigorous XSS mitigation strategies. See, for instance, "[Django XSS: Examples and Prevention](https://www.stackhawk.com/blog/django-xss-examples-prevention/)" from [StackHawk](https://www.stackhawk.com/).

Test the flow of obtaining a CSRF token and session cookie upon login. Verify that subsequent requests from React include the CSRF token in the header and the session cookie automatically (even though the JavaScript cannot read the `sessionid` cookie due to the `HttpOnly` flag).

---

> I'm still getting Forbidden: /api/user (after register/login, and then I reload the page).
> You can find my settings.py and the logs here: https://gist.github.com/axilaris/f0f41dc843c05d0f4cfd40cfefb3478e.
>
> I do undertand generally the flow how front end should ensure `withCredentials = True`, and I think `CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True`.
> The rest I'm not to sure.
>
> I am using port 80 in Docker, so I have disabled `SECURE` for `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False` and `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False`. What is the problem why is it still Forbidden ?

Given that the React frontend and Django backend are likely running on different ports (even if they are on the same localhost), proper CORS configuration is key: you have mentioned that [`CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS` is set to `True`](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/#cors-allow-credentials-bool), which is necessary for requests that include credentials like cookies and authorization headers. However, making sure that the frontend's origin is explicitly allowed in the Django backend's CORS settings is also important.
So check`CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS` includes the React application's origin (e.g., `http://localhost:3000` if React runs on port 3000).

You have set [`CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#csrf-cookie-httponly) to `False` and [`CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#csrf-cookie-secure) set to `False` because you are using port 80 and not HTTPS, which is understandable for development. But the CSRF token has also to be properly included in requests after a page reload: the React application needs to send the CSRF token with state-changing requests (e.g., POST, PUT, DELETE) in the headers.

If your Django backend sends the CSRF token as a cookie (`csrftoken`), your application needs to read this cookie and include the token in the headers of subsequent requests. Since `CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY` is set to `False`, you can use JavaScript to access the cookie value.
When making requests to your backend, include the CSRF token in the request headers. With Axios, you can set the headers for each request or globally. If you are using cookies and `axios`, and assuming you have access to the `js-cookie` library or similar for cookie handling, the setup might look like this:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

// Retrieve the CSRF token from the cookie
const csrfToken = Cookies.get('csrftoken');

// Set the CSRF token in the Axios default headers
axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRFToken'] = csrfToken;
```

Then, check that, after reloading the page, the React application still has access to the latest CSRF token and includes it in the headers of requests to `/api/user`.

---

The session cookie settings seem to be correctly configured for development ([`SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#std-setting-SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY) and [`SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#std-setting-SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE)). Do see if the browser is sending the session cookie back to the server after a page reload. The `HttpOnly` flag prevents JavaScript from accessing the cookie, but the browser should automatically handle it and include it in subsequent requests to the backend.

Check also the request headers in the browser's developer tools to confirm that the `sessionid` cookie is being sent with the request to `/api/user`.

Regarding the Django View serving `/api/user`, see if it is correctly configured to handle session authentication and that there are no additional permission checks failing. If the view uses Django REST Framework, verify that `permissions.IsAuthenticated` is set and functioning as expected.
You can use [Django's logging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/logging/) to output session and authentication information in the view serving `/api/user` to make sure the request is correctly authenticated. Confirm there is no mismatch in the session due to any misconfiguration that could lead to a new session being created after a reload, invalidating the previous session.

---

> I have noticed something, the csrftoken from getCookie is `1qJvVnbBRdkPgGBYd8KLK7wDg7KOE2QU`, but in network logs for login response is `rsyLvHLLNAIumReGxLa63PONPM3klYIq`.
> I have even tried to clear the browser cache. I tried both Chrome and MS Edge Browser to verify.

The CSRF token obtained from the cookie (`1qJvVnbBRdkPgGBYd8KLK7wDg7KOE2QU`) does not match the token in the network logs for the login response (`rsyLvHLLNAIumReGxLa63PONPM3klYIq`).

Django generates a unique CSRF token per session or even per form/request in certain circumstances. That means the token can change, especially after login, logout, or other session state changes. The mismatch you are observing suggests that [after login, a new CSRF token is issued](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/csrf/#how-it-works), but the client-side application continues to use the old token.

The issue will come if your client-side code does not read the new token from the cookie after the session state changes.

To address this, make sure your React application updates the CSRF token it uses for subsequent requests anytime the token might have changed, especially after login, logout, or registration actions: make sure to fetch the new CSRF token from the cookie and update the Axios default headers or the headers of any subsequent request with this new token.

```js
// Example function to update CSRF token in Axios headers
function updateCSRFToken() {
    const csrfToken = Cookies.get('csrftoken');
    axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRFToken'] = csrfToken;
}

// Call this function after login, registration, or logout
updateCSRFToken();
```

Also, modify your `useEffect` hook to listen for changes in user authentication state and update the CSRF token accordingly. That might involve restructuring how you manage and track authentication state in your application.

After implementing the token update mechanism, log the CSRF token before making a request to make sure it matches the latest token expected by the server. Use browser developer tools to inspect the `Set-Cookie` headers in the response of your login/register requests to confirm a new CSRF token is issued and make sure subsequent requests are using this new token in their `X-CSRFToken` header.

---

I think in your latest comment, that is precisely what I have done, if you looked [into `App.js`](https://github.com/axilaris/docker-django-react-celery-redis/blob/main/frontend/src/App.js), I have tried to update `csrftoken` from `getCookie` to Axios to `api/register`, `api/login`, `api/user`. Is there a possibility we can read out the correct `Set-Cookie` csrftoken?

True: your code attempts to update the CSRF token from the cookies for each request. But make sure this update happens *after* the cookies have been updated by the server response. That might not be fully effective if the cookie reading and Axios header update occurs before the browser has processed and saved the new `csrftoken` cookie.

After operations that are likely to change the CSRF token (like login or register), explicitly fetch the CSRF token from the cookie again and update the Axios headers. That might seem redundant with the current setup, but making sure this happens as a callback or a subsequent step after the server's response might address timing issues.

```js
// Example: Updating CSRF token explicitly after login
client.post("/api/login", { email, password }).then((response) => {
  // That ensures we read the CSRF token after the response is processed
  const csrfToken = Cookies.get('csrftoken');
  axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRFToken'] = csrfToken;
  console.log("Updated CSRF Token after login:", csrfToken);
  setCurrentUser(true);
  // Additional logic here if needed
});
```

Then, as mentioned before, use the browser's developer tools to inspect the cookies immediately after login and other state-changing operations. Make sure the `csrftoken` cookie is updated in the browser before your application attempts to read it again.

---

> I did a new trick that WORKS. I created a new axios instance on `api/login` and on the `api/user`.
> The surprise is that `api/login` generates a new csrftoken just for the first time in the console print. And then, `api/user` works.
> You can check the [`App.js` code that uses a new axiosInstance](https://gist.github.com/axilaris/1076e8c25c810b03b701d8b49f4fa7f6).
>
> Could you explain why the original `axios.create()` that is can be reusable everywhere does not work?
> I don't like this new method I have developed to create a new connection every time.

When you configure an Axios instance with defaults (like headers), these defaults are fixed at the instance creation time. If a CSRF token changes (which happens during login, logout, or session expiration), the original Axios instance still retains the old token in its defaults: the instance does not automatically update its defaults based on changes in browser cookies or external changes.

If a CSRF token is updated on the server side and sent to the client via a `Set-Cookie` header, updating the cookie in the browser does not automatically update the Axios default headers configured previously. Since `axios.defaults` or an Axios instance's defaults are not dynamically linked to browser cookies, they do not reflect updates unless explicitly set again.

But: creating a new Axios instance for each request, or after key actions like login, would make sure the most current CSRF token from the cookies is used to configure the instance. That approach effectively isolates the state (headers, in this case) of each request, making sure that changes like CSRF token updates are accounted for.

By fetching the CSRF token from the cookies right before creating a new Axios instance, you make sure the instance uses the most up-to-date token. That dynamic configuration process addresses the issue where the original, statically configured instance would not reflect changes in CSRF token values.

While creating a new Axios instance dynamically can solve the immediate problem of stale CSRF tokens, it can also introduce unnecessary overhead and complexity, especially in applications making frequent API calls.And it can lead to code duplication and make managing HTTP configurations more cumbersome.

Instead of creating a new Axios instance for each request, consider implementing a centralized mechanism to manage and update CSRF tokens. For example, you could use Axios interceptors to dynamically set the `X-CSRFToken` header before each request based on the current value of the CSRF token cookie.
Use [Axios request interceptors](https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors) to read the CSRF token from the cookies and set it in the request headers dynamically. That makes sure each request uses the latest token without needing to create new Axios instances.

```js
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    // Retrieve and set the CSRF token here
    config.headers['X-CSRFToken'] = Cookies.get('csrftoken');
    return config;
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. However, I'm still getting Forbidden: /api/user (after register/login, and then I reload the page). You can find my settings.py and the logs here: https://gist.github.com/axilaris/f0f41dc843c05d0f4cfd40cfefb3478e. I do undertand generally the flow how front end should ensure withCredentials = True and I think CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True. The rest I'm not to sure. I am using port 80 in docker, so I have disabled SECURE for CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False and SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False. What is the problem why is it still Forbidden ?

Comment: Is there a way I can help troubleshoot ? Does the logs I gave you help ?

Comment: @Axil I have edited the answer with some debugging suggestions for you to try.

Comment: Thanks. It still doesnt work. I have committed your solution and troubleshooting code into github. You can see some of the summary on the changes and the network logs here: https://gist.github.com/axilaris/8941e1e6254e62e5c96e29e8241d8bba. I have noticed something, the csrftoken from getCookie is 1qJvVnbBRdkPgGBYd8KLK7wDg7KOE2QU but in network logs for login response is  rsyLvHLLNAIumReGxLa63PONPM3klYIq. I'ved even tried to clear the browser cache like this https://imgur.com/a/3Aly1In. I tried both Chrome and MS Edge Browser to verify.

Comment: I think in your latest comment, that is exactly what I have done, if you looked into App.js, I'ved tried to update csrftoken from getCookie to axios to api/register, api/login, api/user. https://github.com/axilaris/docker-django-react-celery-redis/blob/main/frontend/src/App.js. Do you mind if we do a zoom call ? I'ved really searched all over, not sure what is wrong. is there a possibility we can read out the correct Set-Cookie csrftoken ?

Comment: @Axil I have updated the answer to address your last comment.

Comment: I did a new trick that WORKS. I created a new axios instance on api/login and on the api/user. The surprise is that api/login generates a new csrftoken just for the first time in the console print. and then, api/user works. I havent applied the code to github yet but you can check the App.js code that uses a new axiosInstance https://gist.github.com/axilaris/1076e8c25c810b03b701d8b49f4fa7f6. Could you explain why the original axios.create() that is can be reusable everywhere does not work ? I dont like this new method I have developed to create a new connection everytime.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257116/discussion-between-vonc-and-axil).

Comment: Hi @VonC, have you had a chance to check the re-written description. Is there something that is not right ? Previously it was tested with Docker and it only works when each instance of axios is created on each request. When without Docker, meaning running Django:8000 and React:3000 separately on local machine, after clearing cookies, there is no CSRF token registered. CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False so it should be able to read on React side. I think Django is working, but on the React side, its not retrieving and storing the CSRF token.

Comment: @Axil what you see in my answer is what I got so far.

Answer (score 1):

### hello try this,

```
npm install http-proxy-middleware
```

Open the `setupProxy.js` file and add the following code:

```js
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(
    '/api',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://localhost:8000',
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
};
```

other django settings seem ok to me, so dont touch them for now.

### option 2

in `package.json` file, add this attribute at firsst indent level.

`"proxy":"http://localhost:8000"`

google about how cookies are set, you will understand the secure context concept, and why different origins are security issue when setting cookies. explanation not provide for brevity. also make sure, use `/api/...` and relative to it for further requests for the same reason.

personal opinion: django is a good man, react is magician here. the defaults of react are quite tricky to understand, and i missed deadlines, so i left react for sveltkit.

Comment: Thanks, but it didnt work. It has similar result meaning can login but unable to obtain csrftoken and store in as a cookie.
I checked in your recommendation into github for you to check. 
option 1: https://github.com/axilaris/docker-django-react-celery-redis/tree/withhttp-proxy-middleware (just in package.json - proxy at the beginning)
option 2: https://github.com/axilaris/docker-django-react-celery-redis/tree/packagejsonproxy (just src/setupProxy.js)

Comment: I even tried to change from http://localhost:8000" to http://127.0.0.1:8000"

Comment: hi, i tessted your project locally, login and register are ok, but, the cookie is not getting included, it looks cursed AF, i recomment you try auth Bearer method, or JWT for stateful sessions. or start from major react "working" codebase example https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/build-a-to-do-application-using-django-and-react . ill try comitting in repo, once i get free this weekend.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are aware I posted in the main thread. I created a separate branch https://github.com/axilaris/docker-django-react-celery-redis/tree/fetchworks that demonstrate fetch() works with login .  check submitLogin(e) implementation - https://github.com/axilaris/docker-django-react-celery-redis/blob/fetchworks/frontend/src/App.js. I'm not sure how cursed is it, the digitalocean doesnt look much difference accept it doesnt have the sessionauth csrftoken code. what could be the reason behind it I'm not clear.

Comment: hi i dint mean that its a faulty, but i strongly suspect you will run more issues when you take it to production from local. as per my knowledge, setting cookies from different hostnames (incl ports) will cause issues, i tested in postman, and no conflict with django, but if you use set  JWT as cookie/local storage , developer experience will be much better. try clearing all the settings once and use purely django rest framework intended methods. i see you bypassed many settings to get it to work. if fetch works stick with it for small cost of few extra lines... thats the best i can say.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a simple

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://localhost:3000/*',
    'http://localhost:3000/*'

]
```

Could help!

Comment: didnt work. the login (api/login) have csrftoken and sessionid cookies created. but when i refresh the page (localhost:3000), it should call (api/user) Forbidden: /api/user. I checked the csrftoken and sessionid empty. again the funny thing with fetch() it works.